# How can I reference a resource from other region in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have some cases need to reference resources from other region or account when using CDK. Some cases like:

```
ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(
ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetId(
...
```

I above static API, none of them provide a `region`/`account` property. How can I reference the construct from other regions via CDK?

Comment: really? in case of multiple regions deployment, I expect CDK should support something like that.

Comment: Maybe I should write "I don't so" as CloudFormation is region specific. But anyway, I will wait for the normal answer to see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

By utilizing the `fromArn` functions where they are available.

For example, you can reference a cross-region Log Group using [`LogGroup.fromLogGroupArn()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.LogGroup.html#static-fromwbrlogwbrgroupwbrarnscope-id-loggrouparn). If a method like this is not available for the resouce you want to reference, then it's not possible to reference it in CDK.

You could still achieve this by writing a Custom Resource, which is backed by a Lambda function executing arbitrary code and returning arbitrary values - you can use AWS SDK to do the lookup in the required region and return the result or perform operations on the resource.